# Taking photo in android using intent and processing them

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

i want to take a photo using intent in android after which i want to use the methods like face detection nd stuff, provided by the camera class on that photo, so how can i do that?
Thank you

Comment: unclear what you're asking..

Comment: read the documentation provided by Google for Android development. This can easily be found via using Google's or another search engine of your choice.

Comment: for taking images we have 2 methods 1- using intents 2- using camera class. so when we use camera class to capture images we have tons of methods to process and retrieve some information. For ex the face detection method. So i wanted to ask that how can i use these methods of camera class on the image captured through intent

Comment: what you done till now?please ask question in manner i mean in the way like stack overflow allow to ask the question

Comment: i have an image captured using intent and an image view displaying that captured image

Comment: http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/face-detection-with-android-apis.html this is sample demo may be help you

Comment: ok thanx @AjayPandya